# Hide icon and rating when there is no rating entered

Tags: icon

Some newbie question regarding PHP. I need to hide star icon when there is no rating for the post:

```
<span class="js-average-rating"><i class="star"></i> <?php echo get_average_listing_rating( $post->ID, 1 ); ?></span>
```

So I need to hide  when no rating is inserted.

Thanks!

Comment: What is returned by `get_average_listing_rating()` when no rating is inserted?  Empty string, 0, array?

Comment: Returns empty string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply check that the rating is not empty before printing the markup you wish to make conditional:

```
<?php 
$rating = get_average_listing_rating( $post->ID, 1 );
if ( ! empty( $rating ) ) { ?>
    <span class="js-average-rating"><i class="star"></i> <?php echo $rating; ?></span>
<?php } ?>
```

Without seeing this in context, it's possible you need the outer span to maintain alignment or something else.  If so, just move what you need outside of the condition test.

Comment: Thanks a bunch worked great. To make it compliant with theme check: <?php echo esc_attr ($rating); ?>